# Deep mutable seralizing iOS dictionaries / arrays

Tags: ios, json, ios5, nsmutablearray

Some jSON comes from a local file that my app decomposes : `{"1":{"name":"My List","list":[]}}`.

I use this iOS 5.1 code to convert the entire thing into what I assume to be a *deep* mutable dictionary, due to the options utilized:

```
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:jSONFile];
NSMutableDictionary *mydict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Given the option `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` I would assume that the child array `list` would be fall into this category: "NSJSONReadingMutableContainers - Specifies that arrays and dictionaries are created as mutable objects." from the [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but when I try to execute the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *myarray = [mydict objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"list"];
[myarray addObject:@"test"];
```

Execution explodes on the second line (addObject) with the following exceptions:

-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x887e840

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x887e840'

From my SO research ([1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220120/nsmutablearray-addobject-nsarrayi-addobject-unrecognized-selector-sent-t&ei=pBOcT_n2GOaoiAK8utVj&usg=AFQjCNFg1tWqTv4Zg3qbGsqUzLsyynZkAQ&sig2=n0pQUAdm_LKTxhdw1-7Izw), [2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893043/iphone-crash-using-addobject-on-a-nsmutablearray&ei=pBOcT_n2GOaoiAK8utVj&usg=AFQjCNGB5QHihwvWYP5QewVr536GnjnhrA&sig2=WiiXstpq7qw49Yx8sXHCiA), [3](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEwQFjAD&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676789/nsmutablearray-addobject-unrecognized-selector&ei=pBOcT_n2GOaoiAK8utVj&usg=AFQjCNEDfwZIZTHcD7MPCPVycAlDknaBww&sig2=ZzR23-1e-S61VcRxSQhuyw)), it seems that the above error is generally caused when the element (dictionary / array) with which the object is attempting to be added to is *not* mutable. Furthermore, from my SO research ([1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788690/objective-c-how-to-check-if-variable-is-nsarray-or-nsmutablearray&ei=KBScT4P0D4SQiQLsoqhF&usg=AFQjCNFniTUmeKYR6lb49oQmMl3Xg_lvEg&sig2=qoVBRVV3Rd6gMqXXniSq-Q), [2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235965/ios-distinguish-an-nsdictionary-from-an-nsmutabledictionary&ei=KBScT4P0D4SQiQLsoqhF&usg=AFQjCNHuZ-2Ia5swv98C7XbfLYOHu2-1iA&sig2=zw2wro0u61b5gag5btGVMQ)), it seems that there is no way to test if an object is indeed mutable in obj-c, and that is by design.

So I guess my question is, how can I ensure that my jSON structure is indeed 'deep' mutable upon (or immediately after) serialization? I know I can't use `mutableCopy` on `mydict` because that function is shallow. Any direction / solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this implementation which uses a category on nsdictionary to do a mutable deep copy and works great:

[deep mutable copy of a NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950361/deep-mutable-copy-of-a-nsmutabledictionary)

So after you deserialize the json, you could just call mutableDeepCopy on it.

This is what I have:

```
@interface NSDictionary(Category)
- (NSMutableDictionary *)mutableDeepCopy;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(Category)
- (NSMutableDictionary *)mutableDeepCopy{
    NSMutableDictionary * ret = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                             initWithCapacity:[self count]];

   NSMutableArray * array;

   for (NSString* key in [self allKeys]){

       if([[self objectForKey:key] respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopyWithZone:)]){
            array = [(NSArray *)[self objectForKey:key] mutableCopy];
           [ret setValue:array forKey:key];
       }
       else{
            [ret setValue:[self objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

       }
    }

    return ret;
}

@end
```

Comment: Quite nice. I had to amend a bit since my dictionaries contain dictionaries which contain arrays.

Comment: @AuthmanApatira could you post your code that works with dictionaries in dictionaries? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple had a solution for this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html

"This call produces a mutable array with mutable dictionaries in each element. Each key and each value in each dictionary are themselves also mutable."